# PHP BigQuery Client Error Code: 401 running long job

Tags: php, laravel, google-bigquery

I got a PHP BigQueryClient that I use to export big tables to csv from BQ, but after running for a while they throw and error with code 401:

```php
 Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException 

  {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid Credentials",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",     
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

it occurs when running a long while that goes over the rows of the table like this

```php
$bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
            'keyFile' => $array[$key],
            'projectId' => $this->projectId
        ]);

        //This is to get total row count so we can loop over it
        $info = $bigQuery->dataset($this->datasetId)->table($tableName)->info();

        //Output row count, and status message
        $this->info($this->messagePrepend . "Rows: " . number_format($info['numRows']) . ", Chunk size: " . number_format($this->chunkSize) . " – Processing.." . PHP_EOL);

        $startTime = Carbon::now();

        //Open our output file
        $file = fopen(storage_path("tmp/{$tableName}.csv"), 'w');
        fputcsv($file, $this->tableHeaders);

        $orderBy = match ($keyword) {
            default => "id"
        };

        while ($info['numRows'] > $offset) {

            $config = $bigQuery->query("SELECT * FROM {$this->datasetId}.{$tableName} ORDER BY {$orderBy} ASC LIMIT {$this->chunkSize} OFFSET {$offset}");
            $job = $bigQuery->startQuery($config);
            $queryResults = collect($job->queryResults());

            $queryResults->map(function ($row) {
                $line = [FORM LINE]

                fputcsv($file, $line);
            });

            $offset += $this->chunkSize;
        }
```

I've tried looking for the causes for this, and it seems like the issue is that the client token expires after an hour.

Despite that I've not found a way to refresh it, cause it doesn't seem to do so automatically, could anyone help me figure out how to do that?

I've read [cloud bigquery docs](https://cloud.google.com/php/docs/reference/cloud-bigquery/latest) but they didn't provide me with much answers, and neither did google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved it by updating the instance of BigQueryClient when an exception is thrown:

```php
try {
    $job = $bigQuery->startQuery($config);
} catch (\Throwable $th) {
    $this->warn("Code: " . $th->getCode() . ": " . $th->getMessage(), 'vvv');
    $bigQuery = new BigQueryClient([
        'keyFile' => $array[$key],
        'projectId' => $this->projectId
    ]);

    $job = $bigQuery->startQuery($config);
}
```